# Is it good to represent a newsletter subscription form with captcha in the front page?

Tags: captcha

Is it good to represent a newsletter subscription form with captcha in the front page?

I need form my front page to be as simple as much as I can. I can hide it and let it shown in a popup panel or another page, the two solutions are somehow complicated to the subscriber, without mentioning the mobile. so I am between two solution both are not so good.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fue6xj.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide an image or mockup to ilustrate the situation?

Comment: I have just updated my question

Comment: What is the single primary goal of this page? To get newsletter subscribers or to display your Lorem Ipsum content? Also, is there a specific reason you need a CAPTCHA tool for subscribers?

Comment: this is the landing page ... the primary goal of the website is to build a scientific hub between scientist in some filed like Agriculture for example. The reason I put a CAPTCHA  is to limit the robotic attach over the email server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential solution for keeping the homepage clean is to have the subscription form expand (with animation) when it gains focus, thus displaying the captcha.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIifWy.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

And when the user clicks on the text field:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3QJKU.png)</sup>

As soon as the user enters or focus leaves the subscription box, it can shrink back down.  This guarantees the homepage is clean, yet contains all the functionality you want.